Sql Agent jobs, execution contexts, run as issues
We're on Sql Server 2019.
We have a whole bunch of Sql Agent jobs and pretty much by default they are owned by sa.
The company security team issued an edict that all sa accounts are to be disabled for security reasons, and that's sent me down a bit of a rathole.
We have one Sql Agent job that started failing.  When it fails, it has the error
Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: The account is disabled.

I thought, okay, that makes sense; we disabled the account.  So I went down several paths to try and fix it.

Change the ownership to some other account.  I tried a bunch, but they were all privileged accounts, and I still kept getting the same error.  I found a post on a forum that said Sql Server will default any privileged account to run as sa instead.

I tried changing the Run As user on the Advanced section of the job step.  That changed the error to
Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted

Then I found I couldn't unset that attribute on the task definition - I could only change who it pointed to, and that got me back to "sa is disabled"

Then I realized that we have a bunch of agent jobs owned by sa and only this one is failing.  I don't see the configuration differences that would account for why this 1 fails and they other 10-20 that are owned by sa aren't.  We haven't set up proxies and generally haven't tried changing Run As anywhere.


Any pointers would be appreciated.
Thanks

That error.... I think you should look into the linked server that it's trying to use.  I bet the security is set to map between your local sa and another login on the remote, so you should just add the account you are trying to use to that and it should work again.

Thank you for the reply.  I hadn't thought of the linked server angle!

I'm curious how Joathan deduced that you re using a linked server without that info in the post. Perhaps some info was removed to a comment edited out. Anyhow, I agree with the general line of thought: Check that that jobs does, the contents of the jobsteps. That has to be why it is failing. We disable all our sa, and many many of our jobs are owned by sa (on some 500 SQL instances).

@TiborKaraszi, the error "Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted"  makes us think there is "remote server"involved, i.e. linked server

@user1664043 Please check this answer here, it is similar situation and there you'll find an answer for what loginshould you use in Run As  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526198/access-to-the-remote-server-is-denied-because-the-current-security-context-is-no

Just a follow-up - I checked the failing job's steps and, sure enough, it has a linked server reference in a query.  Great catch, Jonathan!

Thanks for the post link, sepupic.  It's interesting that I didn't get the "Access to remote server" error until I tried switching the Run As user.  "sa is disabled" covered up the fact that it was a remote server access that was throwing the error.

@JonathanFite that was exactly it.  If you want to put it as an answer, I can mark it correct so you get the points

When I saw that the error listed was
Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted

I knew that it was related to a linked server issue.  I surmise that the linked server used login mapping so that only specific users (such as sa) were able to connect to the remote server and/or that the mapped user on the remote did not have sufficient permissions.
... perhaps better explained below.
Possibility A: That only the sa user was mapped to the remote server, therefore prohibiting all other logins from using the remote server.
Possibility B: that the new user DID have a mapped user but didn't map to a user with enough privileges on the remote.
In either case, I advised OP to check the linked server configuration and make sure that the new user had sufficient permissions throughout the chain; which was apparently the solution.
Glad to be of assistance.
